# attachable flexVolume on GKE not working

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm in the process of writing my own flexVolume driver on a `1.10.2-gke.3` cluster and ran into troubles getting it to work in attachable mode.

The driver works in non-attachable mode but then `ReadWriteOnce` doesn't enforce mounting on only one node at a time which is a requirement for my driver and the ultimate goal I'm trying to achieve here.

I made the driver attachable by returning the capability in the `init` call:
`{"status": "Success", "capabilities": {"attach": true}}`

Then, when creating a pod that references the volume with this driver, only `getvolumename` gets called. It doesn't really matter what I return here or if I implement the call at all. This is also the only invocation of the driver, i.e. never gets called for `attach` etc.

The logs indicate that the volume is not registered as in use by the node:

```
kubelet[1910]: W0712 flexVolume driver a3cloud/glusterloop: using default GetVolumeName for volume a3cloud-system-test
kubelet[1910]: I0712 operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "a3cloud-system-test" (UniqueName: "flexvolume-a3cloud/glusterloop/a3cloud-system-test") pod "test-56c867dd4d-75hwc" (UID: "4f633bb6-85b1-11e8-adb3-42010a9c0fc8")
kubelet[1910]: E0712 Operation for "\"flexvolume-a3cloud/glusterloop/a3cloud-system-test\"" failed. No retries permitted until 2018-07-12 08:57:24.360177039 +0000 UTC m=+64585.959480766 (durationBeforeRetry 2m2s). Error: "Volume has not been added to the list of VolumesInUse in the node's volume status for volume \"a3cloud-system-test\" (UniqueName: \"flexvolume-a3cloud/glusterloop/a3cloud-system-test\") pod \"test-56c867dd4d-75hwc\" (UID: \"4f633bb6-85b1-11e8-adb3-42010a9c0fc8\") "
```

According to [this issue comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47109#issuecomment-307265137), as well as the [the docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/flexvolume.md%20the%20docs) if the kubelet is started with `--enable-controller-attach-detach` option the driver must also be installed on the master. Looking at the running processes, this option is not set, but may be a default in the meantime?

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to write an flexVolume driver with attachable support without having it to install on the master?
- Is it possible to install flexVolume driver on a GKE master?
- Is there any other way I can ensure that my volume is mounted on only one node at a time (without hacking up my own locking solution)?

Thanks!

Comment: GKE masters are managed by Google, so you can't access the master.

Comment: My guess would be that it's not possible to write a flexVolume driver with attachable support without having it to install on the master. However, for this question and the other question (mounting volume on only one node at a time) please contact the GKE team. They are available on Slack: http://slack.k8s.io/.

Answer (score 0):

In summary, GKE masters are managed by Google, so you can't access the master. It seems it's not possible to write a flexVolume driver with attachable support without having it to install on the master. However, for this question and the other question (mounting volume on only one node at a time) we recommend contacting the GKE team. They are available on Slack: [slack.k8s.io](http://slack.k8s.io/).